# Issues with Proguard using Gradle in a non-Android project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate the code of my Java project with Proguard. This project has been created on Intellij and is configured with Gradle 2.2.1. There is a proxy on the computer I work on so Intellij can not access the Internet.

I tried for hours to find a simple example to obfuscate my code.

I tried to do :

```
task proguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) { println "ha"}
task proguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) << { println "ha"}
```

and I got an exception every time :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':proguardTask'.
> Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at proguard.ClassPath.get(ClassPath.java:77)
```

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
// Configuration des library java
project.ext.LIBJava = [
        "project1",

        "project2", "project2",
        "project2_OS", "project2_UI",
        "project3",
        "project3_Windows"
]

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ext.buildOnline = false
ext.buildOnlineMapsforge = false
ext.buildAndroid = false

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir dirs: 'C:/Path/To/Proguard/proguard-5.1/lib'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard'
    }
}

def filterProjects(filter) { return subprojects.findAll { project -> filter.contains(project.name) } }


allprojects {
    group = 'org.libWin'
    version = '0.1.1'
}

// Configuration injection for all subprojects
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

task proguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    println "ha"
}

configure(filterProjects(project.LIBJava)) {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        if (buildOnline) { // On-line
            testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: 4.11           //  "$jUnitVersion"
        }
    }

    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Does anyone know where the problem comes from ? How to obfuscate easily my code with Proguard using Gradle ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You must specify injars in your Proguard task.

Example:

```
task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    injars "build/libs"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could obfuscate with proguard a non-Android project with the plugin `proguard-gradle` .

- Specify your proguard configurations (keep options) in a file
- Specify input & output jars
- Specify the dependencies (jars) which your project referred to.

  ```
  buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3'
       classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.0.3'
   }
  }
  def dependsDir = "${buildDir}/libs/dependencies/"
  def outputJar = "${buildDir}/libs/${rootProject.name}.jar"

  task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {

   configuration 'proguard.conf'
   injars "${outputJar}"
   outjars "${buildDir}/libs/${rootProject.name}_proguard.jar"

   libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
   libraryjars "${dependsDir}"
  }
  ```
- Add the above gradle task to your build.gradle
- Execute `gradle proguard`